# Python Numpy Should I create new Arrays or Overwrite the old ones?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python numpy for my matrices and would like to know which way of coding style is more efficient according to computational costs and which one according to memory cost.

In the first example I create everytime a new Array, in the second I would overwrite the same one.

```
def pipeline1(input, k1, k2, k3):
    A = np.array([input.x, input.y])
    B = np.dot(A, k1)
    C = B + k2 / k3

def pipeline2(input, k1, k2, k3):
    A = np.array([input.x, input.y])
    A = np.dot(A, k1)
    A = A + k2 / k3
```

Which way is the more efficient way? Does it make any difference? This is an example.

Comment: Computation is obviously the same. Memory is obviously worse in the first call since you keep all intermediate results (until the function ends)... Although in practice python does the garbage collection for you so there is no guarantee second function will actually have better memory footprint.

Comment: Unless your arrays are so large that you get memory errors with the first, use which ever is clearer to you.  The variables are all local.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are small like this then memory would not be an issue for either, but the second option would fair better in larger arrays.